# Can I install a hard drive with XP and hard drive with Windows 10 in a new computer?

Tags: windows-xp

I have an old computer loaded with XP, old software, and old files which don't work in Windows 10. I have a new computer, Dell Precision 3630 Tower, loaded with Windows 10. May I install the hard drive with XP into my new computer? Can I run them separately?

Comment: This is not recommended due to the massive security risk WinXP is.  It would be better to create a VHD of the WinXP HDD and utilize it within a virtual machine on Windows 10, however, WinXP is still a massive security risk and it would be better to ditch it altogether.  WinXP software can be ran on Windows 10 via Compatibility Mode (right-click executable > Properties > Compatibility)

Comment: It will never work, there are no drivers for XP and that new hardware.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

CorelDraw 8 with ME fonts does not open in Windows 10. I tried all of the compatibility options to no avail. Even in Windows 8.1, CorelDraw 8 files opened up, but the text/fonts were unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The new PC will have modern hardware, for which many of the XP drivers that you would need do not exist. I would advise keeping the XP drive in the old computer.

Not only will this avoid any problems with drivers but users won't need to deal with the potentially frustrating workflow of changing the boot order in order to access their legacy applications. You could use the XP system without worrying too much about security if you prevented it from accessing the network by disabling its network adapter, but I wouldn't go so far as actually trying to boot it in the new PC. Even if it did boot, which it almost certainly wouldn't be able to do, it would be a very unstable system.

I think you would be better off just running both PCs separately in this situation.

Comment: Not just drivers, but UEFI.

Comment: True. There are multiple deal breakers!

Comment: Just a suggestion -- adding an edit with contradictory information makes the answer confusing (even bad guidance if the reader just runs with the first part).  It's better to rewrite the answer to make it a single, cohesive one.

Comment: Good thinking. I'll merge it properly. I was also thinking that technically, you probably could switch the motherboard to legacy mode and get it to run with XP. It would be convoluted and a poor user experience for a dual-boot system, but provided the new PC's BIOS supported legacy mode, it would at least be an option. On the other hand, the lack of driver support would be an insolvable problem⁠. I think that's why I didn't mention the UEFI issue in my answer: I felt there was arguably a workaround for it and only wanted to include certain deal breakers, in the interest of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it's not impossible to run XP on new hardware if you have enough experience. But I would argue that you should have enough experience so you don't have to ask this question in the first place.

So I would advise a different solution:

Convert your old PC into a virtual machine image using e.g. VM-Ware. This way you can run a "virtual old PC" (with Win XP) inside your new one (with Win 10). In this configuration they are "sort of" separated, if needed you can achieve a higher separation as well.

With a little research, this should be possible for an average user as well. And if you run into problems creating the VM, you could just ask on this site :)

Comment: "Convert your old PC into a virtual machine image using e.g. VM-Ware. This way you can run a "virtual old PC" (with Win XP) inside your new one (with Win 10). In this configuration they are "sort of" separated, if needed you can achieve a higher separation as well."           Is the best and most secure method is run the computers separately with a switch in between? Do I need a "'virtual old PC' (with Win XP) inside your new one (with Win 10)"?

Comment: @dj no it doesn't matter. You can set it up, so the virtual PC runs "seperated" (sandboxed) so it can not influence anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just buying another or using it as a virtual slave drive(which will run the XP drive but will run it in Win10 settings so many things/programs may not be seen as safe or functional & Win10 may disable or remove/move them/it or just make everything slower & effect the CPU), replace the motherboard with a customized or used WinXP motherboard with more of memory slots different graphics or other things you want it to have different than the current one it's in... if you have more money than most AND you aren't planning to connect/use it on the internet (none of my oldest ones are, it seems to prolong them like airdusting inside there). Or just keep them separated.
Years ago I wanted to add a Hard drive to 1 of my WinXP PCs & it never worked (wasn't as much accurate instructions online back then, like how to connect & format the blank drive not all drives or 1 with programs on it. Still have that blank HD). I've also wanted to move at least 1 of my WinXP HDs to a newer Win10 PC, but I don't want to risk another harddrive with so much on it like the part of formatting the hard drive.
But if you want to run them (WinXP & Win10) separately on the same PC, then it's easier & cheaper to do the slavedrive (like an external drive which I have several of for many purposes, or a 2nd hard drive), or VM-ware(which is more a a single file which contains a virtual disk that has a bootable operating system installed on it), or just not combine them.
So yes you can....but with limitations of course.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).